# MeteorJS - sync with MongoDb only for logged in users

Tags: meteor

I have an app written in MeteorJS, the functionality is only for logged in users, and all the documents in Mongo have an userId field for each logged in user.
However, I want now to add a "demo" functionality, were on the landing page the user can click instead of "log on" a "try out the demo" button. 
The main difference in functionality would be, that the "demo user" doesn't store anything in the MongoDb database and all data and operations are performed only on the local MiniMongo database.
Is there any easy way to achieve this?

I know about `new Meteor.Collection(null)` that it is only locally, but I define the collection on the global level of the app where I don't have access to `Meteor.userId()' or`this.userId` so it would have to check on every place which collection to use.

Comment: Could you create a restricted regular account for the special user with id "demo"? This may be a lot easier than having two versions of everything

Comment: Nope, because then each "demo user" would share the same data making the demo unusable

Answer (score 0):

Ended up with following approach:

On place were I define my collections (shared code between server and client) I define two collections:

```
var Docs = new Meteor.Collection("docs");
var DocsOffline = new MeteorCollection(null);
```

no in each meteor method I access the collection using following variable:

```
let docsSource = Meteor.userId() ? Docs : DocsOffline;
```

and then operate on `docsSource`

On the client in the `getMeteorData` mixin method I have similar approach to make the data available (I use ReactJS)

Comment: It might be simpler to do: `var collectionName = Meteor.userId()? "docs" : null;` and then do `var Docs = new Meteor.Collection(collectionName);` then the rest of your code doesn't have to care.